# Can't read innerHTML from a shadowRoot element in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to read the value (innerHTML/innerText) property of an element using the following but I get an empty string.
`cy.get('#INGLoanRequests-container').shadow().find(Selectors.postCode).invoke('val').then(value => { console.log("post code is " + value) })`

where postCode is just a css selector. Upon checking the console I see [image]

which means the element is being found but the value is not read. But
in firefox dev tools I can access the value of the subject, like so.
[image]

Kindly if someone can spot what I'm doing wrong here, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you want

- `.invoke('html')` to get `.innerHTML`
- `.invoke('text')` to get `.innerText`
- `.invoke('val')` to get the value property of an `<input>`

Answer (score 1):

To get the innerHTML value you have to use `.invoke('text')` -

```
cy.get('#INGLoanRequests-container').shadow().find(Selectors.postCode).invoke('text').then(value => {
    console.log("post code is " + value)
})
```